# Is it possible using HUGO website framework to change the content directory where you store, for example, markdown files?

Tags: go, directory, markdown, hugo

My purpose is to have an empty hugo application, so, using scripts, I can store list of directories with md files or only md files in an external directory, one level above.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question, it's a question for the [hugo community](https://discuss.gohugo.io/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can use the `contentDir` option in your [config file](https://gohugo.io/overview/configuration/), or pass the `-c` or `--contentDir` [flags](https://gohugo.io/commands/hugo/) to Hugo on the command line.